# Would like to display grouped products in a table layout, but also with a price / quantity discount visible

Tags: product, configurable-product, magento-1, grouped-products, product-view

My questions refers to CE.  I'm putting a new store together and I would like to display grouped products in a table layout, but also with a price / quantity discount visible.

As an example of what I'm trying to achieve, please see here: http://www.allpacksolutions.co.uk/product.php?xProd=110&xSec=11

I'm no expert in Magento, I'm pretty new to it to be fair, so I thought I'd ask on here as I'm sure someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

P.S. I'm only assuming here that (based on the example link given) grouped products is the way to go in terms of the type of products to display in this manner?  Configurable products are just for dropdown options correct?  I have however seen examples of extensions that combine these two elements and present them in one table.  So perhaps I'm after something like that, but with a few modifications.

Comment: magenti routing system is different it follow mvc structure.So  you need lot of work

Comment: what's the mvc structure exactly?

Comment: The comment makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Configure tier prices for the simple products. The default template for grouped products already shows the tier prices for each simple product, to change it to a table, you have to

1. override/modify `catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml` in your theme
2. make a copy of `catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml` which will be used only for grouped products. Let's call it `catalog/product/view/type/grouped/tierprices.phtml`. Then in your theme's layout XML, attach this new template to the group view as follows:

   ```
   <PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
       <reference name="product.info.grouped">
           <action method="setTierPriceTemplate">
               <template>catalog/product/view/type/grouped/tierprices.phtml</template>
           </action>
       </reference>
   </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
   ```